# Android SQLite decremente ID

Tags: android, sqlite, integer, decrement

I have a SQLite database like this:

```
    private static final String CREATE_BDD = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTE + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COL_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_NOTE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_COLOR + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

The database stores notes that I can identify by ID. When I remove a note from the database I want all IDs superiore to the ID of the removed note being decremented by one, then I can keep the column ID like "1, 2, 3, 4" than "1, 3, 4" when I remove the note with ID 2.

Because I use this to read all my notes (with BDDManager my DAO) and I'd like not using a List to get all notes:

```
    private void readAllNotes(){
    int i = 1;
    Note note = new Note();
    BDDManager.open();

    do{
        note = BDDManager.getNoteWithId(i);

            if(note != null){
                addCard(note); //here I add the note to a new TextView
                i++;
            }

    }while(note != null);

       BDDManager.close();
}
```

And when I remove a note I can't read after the removed ID because it returns **null** and stop read notes after a removed note

Here is how I remove a note:

```
    public int removeNoteWithId(int id){

    return bdd.delete(TABLE_NOTE, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, when doing something like this, my first intuition is that you should lock the table. Second, you could just use your DAO to loop through all the notes and have each one update themselves (or make a call to the DAO).

```
public int removeNoteWithId(int id){
    for(Note n : notes)
    {
        n.decrementID();//OR decrement(n.getID);
    }
    return bdd.delete(TABLE_NOTE, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);
}
```

Also, instead of changing id's all the time, you should consider having an extra column for position ordering. That way you can use the id to ensure uniqueness and for indexing and use the other column for ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key may not possible to change once it is created. Why are you not trying to use **SELECT * FROM TABLE_NOTE;** ? After getting result call addcard(note) according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for long reply, night here (France)

Finally I did like bean5 said.
And I'm a noob :p
I was just searching something "automatic", maybe to avoid some I/O in database

```
private void updateAllId(int id){

    Note note = new Note();

    do{

        note = getNoteWithId(id+1);
        if(note != null){

            note.setId(id);
            updateNoteId(id++, note);

        }

    }while(note != null);

}

public int updateNoteId(int id, Note note){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_ID, note.getId());

    return bdd.update(TABLE_NOTE, values, COL_ID + " = " +id, null);

}
```

Thanks all ! Problem solved